# Completion of a subspace of $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

We have a hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb C )=\{ \{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \in \mathbb C: \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2 < \infty  \}$ and a subset $S = \{ \{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \in \mathbb C: x_n \neq 0 \text{ for finitely many n} \} $. I proved that it is a subspace but not a complete subspace. I need to discuss its completion...

What I am thinking is to take a sequence of sequences $\{e_n^i\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ where $e_n^i$ is "$0$" $\forall i \neq n$ and "$1$" for $i=n$. And then take $span(\{e_n^i : n \in \mathbb N\})$. Will it be a completion or there is any other way to find the completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you have is on the right track.

Let $\{\delta_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the canononical orthonormal basis of $\ell^2$. Then
$$S= \operatorname{span}\{\delta_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$
By definition of orthonormal basis, the closure of $S$ is $\ell^2$. Hence, $S$ is not complete because it is not closed.

Comment: So the completion of $S$ is the whole space?

Comment: @BssK Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to proceed would be to show that $S$ is dense in $l^2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Does it mean that the completion of $S$ is the $l^2 (\mathbb C)$ itself?

Comment: @BssK yes it does.